# Resizing a rotated item with javascript (interact.js)

Tags: javascript, resize, interact.js

I have spent many days trying to make an item resizable that is rotated with [interact.js](http://interactjs.io/).

This is the code that I have at this moment, I will try to explain the concept.

We have a selector item for two reasons, because the container could be scaled with css transform (like a zoom), and we need to have the selector outside and because we have a multiselection, and the selector grow if I have two rectangle selected, but in this case this is not the main problem and we have calculated the scaled proportion without problems and other things.

When the selector is resize, it take the rectangle, and make the same with the width, height, left, top and rotation.

**Javascript:**

```
// TAP - CLICK EVENT (just for positioning the selector)
interact('#rectangle').on('tap', event => {
  console.log('Tap Box!');
  event.stopPropagation();
  const $rectangleCloned = $('#rectangle').clone();
  const previousTransform = $rectangleCloned.css('transform');
  $rectangleCloned.css('transform', 'none');
  $rectangleCloned.css('opacity', '0');
  $rectangleCloned.css('display', 'block');


  $('#container').append($rectangleCloned);
  const values = $rectangleCloned[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  // This is just a trick for fast implementation:
  $('#selector').css('top', values.y);
  $('#selector').css('left', values.x);
  $('#selector').css('width', values.width);
  $('#selector').css('height', values.height);
  $('#selector').css('transform', previousTransform);

  $rectangleCloned.remove();
  return values;
});


interact('.pointer9').draggable({
  max: 1,
  onmove: event => {
    const angleDeg =
      Math.atan2(
        centerRotate.posY - event.pageY,
        centerRotate.posX - event.pageX
      ) *
      180 /
      Math.PI;

    console.log(this.rotate);
    const prevAngle = this.rotate - angleInitial;
    const angle = parseInt(angleDeg) + prevAngle;
    this.$rectangle.css({
      transform: 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
    this.$selector.css({
      transform: 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
  },
  onstart: event => {
    const data = event.interactable.getRect(event.target.parentNode);
    this.centerRotate = {
      posX: data.left + data.width / 2,
      posY: data.top + data.height / 2
    };
    this.angleInitial =
      Math.atan2(
        centerRotate.posY - event.pageY,
        centerRotate.posX - event.pageX
      ) *
      180 /
      Math.PI;
    this.$rectangle = $('#rectangle');
    this.$selector = $('#selector');
    this.rotate = $rectangle.attr('angle') || 0;
  },
  onend: event => {
    const $box = $('#selector');
    const matrix = $box.css('transform');
    const values = matrix
      .split('(')[1]
      .split(')')[0]
      .split(',');

    var a = values[0];
    var b = values[1];
    var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
    $rectangle.attr('angle', angle);

  }
});


interact('#selector')
  .resizable({
    // resize from all edges and corners
    edges: {
      left: true,
      right: true,
      bottom: true,
      top: true
    },

    // keep the edges inside the parent
    restrictEdges: {
      outer: 'parent',
      endOnly: true,
    },

    // minimum size
    restrictSize: {
      min: {
        width: 100,
        height: 50
      },
    },

    inertia: true,
  })
  .on('resizemove', function(event) {
    var target = event.target,
      x = parseFloat($(target).offset().left) || 0,
      y = parseFloat($(target).offset().top) || 0;

    // update the element's style
    target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

    // translate when resizing from top or left edges
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    target.style.left = x + 'px';
    target.style.top = y + 'px';

    $('#rectangle')[0].style.left = target.style.left;
    $('#rectangle')[0].style.top = target.style.top;

    $('#rectangle')[0].style.width = target.style.width;
    $('#rectangle')[0].style.height = target.style.height;

    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);

  });
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

#rectangle {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

#selector {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: -1000px;
  /*Not showing at start*/
}

#selector .pointers {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#selector .pointers .point {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#selector .pointers.pointer1 {
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}

#selector .pointers.pointer2 {
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}

#selector .pointers.pointer3 {
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}

#selector .pointers.pointer4 {
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}

#selector .pointers.pointer-north {
  top: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}

#selector .pointers.pointer-south {
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}

#selector .pointers.pointer-east {
  right: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
}

#selector .pointers.pointer-west {
  left: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
}

#selector .pointer-rotate {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: rotate;
}

#selector .pointer9 {
  bottom: -70px;
  left: calc(50% - 11px);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: absolute;
}

#selector .rotate-line {
  border-left: 1px dashed #5f5f5f;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  width: 1px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="rectangle">
  </div>
  <div id="selector">
    <div class="pointers pointer1">
      <div class="point"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pointers pointer2">
      <div class="point">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pointers pointer3">
      <div class="point">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pointers pointer4">
      <div class="point">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pointers pointer-north">
      <div class="point">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pointers pointer-east">
      <div class="point">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pointers pointer-south">
      <div class="point">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pointers pointer-west">
      <div class="point">
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="topline lines-resize" />
    <span class="rightline lines-resize" />
    <span class="botline lines-resize" />
    <span class="leftline lines-resize" />
    <div class="pointer-rotate pointer9" />
    <div class="rotate-line" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle for testing:

https://jsfiddle.net/ub70028c/46/

I have read about other people trying to make the same without not results...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I checked your code and a similar library for `resizable` and `rotatable` and I figure out your problem.

First, checking similar library:

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/q6ofdbdf/6/) that I created by [**jquery.freetrans.js**](https://github.com/gthmb/jquery-free-transform).

If you inspect on `<div class="shape">`, you can see

```
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

If you rotate it, `transform` changed like below:

```
transform: matrix(0.997373, -0.0724379, 0.0724379, 0.997373, 0, 0);
```

In similar case, [your code](https://jsfiddle.net/ub70028c/46/) uses `transform` that at first, it doesn't `transform` and after rotating, it has like below:

```
transform: rotate(-2.49576deg);
```

If you can use `matrix` instead of `rotate` in `transform`, your code will work properly. If you can't change it, you can use similar library like `jquery.freetrans.js`that work properly with rotate and resize together.

Comment: I want the maths to do it... but thanks. We are close to get it working... even with multiple items at the same time. We are working in this moment with a mathematician and he is supporting us to make the code works. He is working with a lot of trigonometric.

Comment: @chemitaxis have you reached a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/569

https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/499

https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/394

I am afraid you have chosen a library whose author has clearly stated his intent

> There's no built-in way. As I mentioned in [`#137`](https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/137) I'm not really interested in handling scaled or rotated elements

So the question you should ask yourself is

> Do I want to find a workaround to make this library work or choose a different library perhaps?

**Update-1: 28-Apr-2018**

In case you want to do it in canvas instead of normal elements then I found [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) a good option

[image: FabricJS]

Comment: I would suggest you pickup another library even if the math needs to be figured out. Because you don't want to pickup something which will not go the way where you want to. I will see if I can post more details about the equations

Comment: Thanks! I don't know any library that do that, and jquery-free-transform is very old... and the maths is very "harcoded".

Comment: Another comment, Interact.js for us is the best, because it give you all the data for make your own operations... delta, edges, etc.

Answer (score 0):

we are very close to finish the work after five days... we need to optimice all the mathematical calculations... but yes, this is what I was looking for:

[image]

Sorry, but we don't have the code ready... I will post all with comments for other people.

**Comments:** For a mathematician, this task is not very complex because all the angles are rectangular (90º). I will try to make a PR to the Interact.js, even to other libraries to implement this feature by default. Hope this work help to other developers ;)

Comment: can you share the math for the transform matrix. I am also stuck :(

Comment: Hi @chemitaxis, have you find suitable solution for interact.js? If yes, could you share your workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes please, I would love a solution to this using InteractJS - it does everything I want, but the 'flicker` caused by resizing a rotated element is frustration and feels clunky.